# SSH_ORIGINAL_ENVIRONMENT error with Snow Leopard client to a gitosis server on Debian

Tags: debian, osx-snow-leopard, git

I have a server running gitosis (installed from the package manager) on Debian Lenny. I am able to perform all operations from my linux mint laptop, but from my Mac running an up-to-date Snow Leopard gives me the following error:

```
mica@waste Desktop$ git clone gitosis@192.168.0.156:Poems.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/micas/Desktop/Poems/.git/
ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Repository read access denied
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
mica@waste Desktop$ ssh -v gitosis@192.168.0.156
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.156 [192.168.0.156] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/micas/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/micas/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/micas/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '192.168.0.156' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/mica/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/mica/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: gitosis-serve mica@waste
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: Remote: Forced command: gitosis-serve micas@waste
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Need SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND in environment.
                                                                  debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to 192.168.0.156 closed.
Transferred: sent 2544, received 2888 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 29642.1, received 33650.3
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Extensive googling of the error isn't returning much-- I changed the /etc/sshd_config file on my Mac as per http://www.schmidp.com/2009/06/23/enable-ssh-agent-key-forwarding-on-snow-leopard/. I still get the same error.

Comment: Is there already a Poems.git repository there for you to clone? Does either of the users `mica` or `micas` have read permission on it in gitosis.conf?

Comment: Yeah, the poems.git repo is there, I can pull all my repos to my linux laptop. in my gitosis.conf, the micas & mica user has permissions to all repos.

Comment: and... this was working while i was running leopard. i've already switched rsa keys.

Comment: was it sshd_config or ssh_config that you edited?

Comment: turns out i didn't need to actually edit either; i had my list of users in the gitosis.conf file seperated with commas, however the users are space seperated. so gitosis was looking for `user@domain,` instead of `user@domain`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, gitosis is no longer maintained, i will be moving to gitolite soon. My problem was that i was using a comma to separate the users in my gitosis.conf file, but users should just be space separated.